# checking slope = $0$ at a point for a function using $\epsilon $, $\delta $ definition

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

From the continuity definition, a function is continuous at a point $a$ if  : $$\forall \epsilon \gt 0 \exists \delta \gt 0  : |x-a| \lt \delta \implies |f(x)-f(a)|\lt \epsilon$$

If I change the order of quantifiers like below do I get a definition for checking slope = $0$ at $x = a$ ? 
$$\exists \delta \gt 0   \forall \epsilon \gt 0 : |x-a| \lt \delta \implies |f(x)-f(a)|\lt \epsilon$$

---

If my interpretation of second quantifier order is flawed, could you please tell me how to interpret it correctly in this context ? I realized that order matters by going through other mse posts already.

Comment: Your condition is for example true for all bounded functions. If $|f(x)| < M$ then $|f(x) - f(a)| < 2M$ so for all $\delta > 0$ we just take $\epsilon = 2M$

Comment: Does that mean the latter quantifier order need not suggest a constant function is it ?

Comment: That is correct. Any bounded function, continuous or not, satisfy it.

Comment: sorry looks the user who has edited changed the second expression, il change it quickly really sorry

Comment: I have corrected it, kindly check once.. I am just changing the order of quantifiers...

Comment: This works: it now says that there exist an interval around $a$ where $f(x)$ is constant.

Comment: Woah! makes sense xD thank you so much ! if possible could you post an answer so that I upvote you and close the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order of the quantifies matters a lot. The statement

$$\exists \delta \gt 0, \forall\epsilon \gt 0 : |x-a| \lt \delta \implies |f(x)-f(a)|\lt \epsilon$$

implies that there exist an interval around $a$ where $f(x)$ is constant. If we change the order of the quantifiers to

$$\forall \delta \gt 0, \exists\epsilon \gt 0 : |x-a| \lt \delta \implies |f(x)-f(a)|\lt \epsilon$$

then for example any function which is bounded will satisfy it since if $|f(x)| < M$ then take $\epsilon = 2M$ to get $|f(x)-f(a)| < \epsilon$ for all $\delta$.